# efcore/temporal tables migration handling

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, ef-core-2.0, temporal-tables

My team and I are using .netcore/ef core/mssql in backend development.
One of our client's requirements is to provide a history over the changes of data.
Our first approach was to query temporal tables for historical related topics.
Although we could figure out how to implement and query temporal tables, we have some
concerns about the use of temporal tables in db schema changes. Our main concern is that nearly every migrations up- and downmethods has to be extended by a good amount of selfwritten SQL-code. Does anyone use temporal tables in production/development and could provide an insight about the handling of migrations?

Answer (score 2):

The most requested feature for EF Core 6.0 was support for SQL Server temporal tables. As of RC1, temporal table support is now included in EF Core.

Reads more [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/prime-your-flux-capacitor-sql-server-temporal-tables-in-ef-core-6-0/).

Answer (score 0):

Did you figure it out?

I'm in the process of implementing history on our tables right now using temporal tables with efcore 3. And I stumbled upon [this](https://www.eidias.com/blog/2018/8/29/using-sql-temporal-tables-with-entity-framework-core) blog post describing, how it could be done. By implementing a generic extension method for the MigrationBuilder you can add temporal tables manually when creating new migrations.

**MigrationBuilderExtensions.cs**

```
public static void AddTemporalTableSupport(this MigrationBuilder builder, string tableName, string historyTableSchema)
{
    builder.Sql($@"ALTER TABLE {tableName} ADD
                SysStartTime datetime2(0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW START HIDDEN NOT NULL,
                SysEndTime datetime2(0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ROW END HIDDEN NOT NULL,
                PERIOD FOR SYSTEM_TIME (SysStartTime, SysEndTime);");
    builder.Sql($@"ALTER TABLE {tableName}
                SET (SYSTEM_VERSIONING = ON (HISTORY_TABLE = {historyTableSchema}.{tableName} ));");
}
```

**And in the bottom of your migration files Up() method.**

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
{
   // ** Migration code **

   migrationBuilder.Sql("CREATE SCHEMA History");
   migrationBuilder.AddTemporalTableSupport("Products", "History");
   migrationBuilder.AddTemporalTableSupport("ProductDetails", "History");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you try this ?

https://github.com/terryfkjc/EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.TemporalTable

This extension can support

1. Create temporal query from Linq
2. add Migrations for temporal table.(work with Add-Migration, Script-Migration)